# Calling child's overridden method from parent class

Tags: c++

I want to practice C++ by coding a simple mobile phone application with an interchangeable system. I created a System base class and also created MyOS class which extends the System class. In the Phone class, I have a variable of System class because I think like in Java, you can assign it with child class. (eg. System sys = new MyOS();). But in C++ it calls the function in the base class.

What I want to work in C++ but it's in Java.

```
public class MyParent {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start() executed in MyParent");
    }
}

public class MyChild extends MyParent {
    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start() excecuted in MyChild");
    }
}

public class Inherit {
    MyParent parent;
    
    public Inherit(MyParent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    
    public void start() {
        parent.start();
    }
}

public class TestInherit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inherit i = new Inherit(new MyChild());
        i.start();
    }
}

Output: start() excecuted in MyChild
```

My current c++ code:

System.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class System {
public:

    void start() {
        std::cout << "Booting System..." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

MyOS.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "System.h"

class MyOS: public System {
public:

    // Override
    void start() {
        std::cout << "Booting MyOS..." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Phone.h

```
#pragma once

#include "System.h"

class Phone {
public:

    Phone(System system) {
        Phone::system = system;
    }

    void start() {
        system.start();
    }

private:

    System system;
};
```

MyPhone.cpp

```
#include "MyOS.h"
#include "Phone.h"
#include "System.h"

int main() {
    MyOS os;
    Phone myPhone(os);
    myPhone.start();

    return 0;
}

Output: Booting System...
```

Comment: What about making that method `virtual`?

Comment: How did it compile? You should get a compiler error. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: `virtual void start()` in System and `void start() override` in MyOS still outputs `Booting System...`

Comment: The reason is System object is not pointer in Phone class. It gets resolved at compile time and system is getting called. Make it a pointer for run time polymorphism

Comment: Read about polymorphism in your favourite C++ book. Don't assume that the differences to Java are just a matter of syntax.

Comment: Your `Phone` should have a **pointer** to a `System`, not a value

Comment: @FOURBITS It looks like you need to learn C++ from [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of guessing how to write C++ code.   The `virtual` keyword is fundamental in getting polymorphism to work in C++.  Also, do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code -- Java is not C++.  As you can see, every function is "virtual" in Java, but that is not the case with C++.

Comment: @FOURBITS `Phone(System system)` -- This is also another difference in C++.  You are passing `System` by value.  You are not passing a reference.  That `system` is temporary, and will be gone when the constructor for `Phone` is completed.  This is much different than Java, where the `system` is a reference to the `System` that is passed.  It's big differences like that which makes it a requirement to *not* use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  If you continue to use Java as a model, your program will be buggy, inefficient, or just look weird to an actual C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're coming from java, you need to remember that every non-primitive variable or field in java is implicitly a pointer, so to make equivalent C++ code, you need to make all interclass references into pointers.

In addition, every method in java is implicitly virtual, so if you want to override them, you need an explicit `virtual` in C++.

So you end up with something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class System {
public:

    virtual void start() {
        std::cout << "Booting System..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyOS: public System {
public:

    // Override
    void start() override {
        std::cout << "Booting MyOS..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Phone {
public:

    Phone(System *system) {
        this->system = system;
    }

    void start() {
        system->start();
    }

private:

    System *system;
};

int main() {
    MyOS os;
    Phone myPhone(&os);
    myPhone.start();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, using raw pointers is a recipe for memory leaks and corruption, as C++ does not have built in garbage collection.  So you generally want to use "smart" pointers instead -- either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your given code:

##### Problem 1

The method `start` is a non-virtual member function so you're not actually overriding it in the `MyOS`.

So first step is to make it virtual as shown below.

##### Problem 2

Moreover, in order for runtime binding to work, you must **make the call to the virtual-member function using a pointer or a reference** to the Base class(which is `System`) object as shown below:

---

##### Solution

Here we make sure that `start` is a virtual member function and also that the data member `system` is an lvalue reference to `System` so that dynamic binding can actually happen.

**MyOS.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "System.h"

class MyOS: public System {
public:

    // Override
    public: void start() override {    //override keyword added here to make the intention clear
        std::cout << "Booting MyOS..." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**System.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class System {
public:

    public:
//--vvvvvvv------------------->virtual keyword added here
    virtual void start() {
        std::cout << "Booting System..." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**Phone.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "System.h"

class Phone {
public:

    Phone(System& psystem):system(psystem){
    }

    void start() {
        system.start();
    }

private:
//--------v----------->lvalue reference to System
    System& system;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyOS.h"
#include "Phone.h"
#include "System.h"

int main() {
    MyOS os;
    Phone myPhone(os);
    myPhone.start();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
Booting MyOS...
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/8XbkaXlAa)

##### Note

Note that we can also make the data member `system` to be a pointer to a `System` object instead of making it an lvalue reference to a `System` object. [Demo with pointer](https://onlinegdb.com/4VoNP_Twl). Also note in some circumstances, classes used as the root of an inheritance hierarchy should define a virtual destructor. Refer to [why virtual destructs are used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: I think in `System.h` you could make it a pure virtual function even.

Comment: @F.Müller I have discussed one possible solution.

Comment: You left out that `MyOS` cannot be used in some circumstances safely, unless a virtual destructor is present.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is completely unnecessary here(in the current situation). I just wanted to explain the basic working.  I don't take responsibility for what you can do by modifying the code. For properly learning something a book has to be used.

Comment: You could link to [why virtual destructors are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added a note at the end of my answer as per your suggestion.